# How to customize the kendo UI Donut Chart?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to customize some aspects of the **donut chart** that I am populating with the following *ASP.NET razor code*:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart()
        .Name("chart")
        .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea
            .Background("transparent"))
        .SeriesDefaults(series =>
            series.Donut().StartAngle(0)
        )
        .Series(series =>
        {
        series.Donut(new dynamic[] {
                new {category = "Asia", value = 25.0, color = "#124324" },
                new {category = "Europe",value = 25.0, color = "#90cc38"},
                new {category = "Latin America",value = 25.0, color = "#068c35"},
                new {category = "Africa",value = 25.0, color = "#006634"}
            }) ...
```

I searched the documentation and I can't find **how to customize the following**:

- Create a gap between each category
- Setting a border color per category

How to customize these aspects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out how to customize these aspects.

### Creating a gap between categories

By setting the explode property to true on each category it is possible to create a gap.

```
series.Donut(new dynamic[] {
                new {category = "Asia", value = 25.0, color = "#124324" , explode = true},
                new {category = "Europe",value = 25.0, color = "#90cc38", explode = true},
                new {category = "Latin America",value = 25.0, color = "#068c35", explode = true},
                new {category = "Africa",value = 25.0, color = "#006634", explode = true}
            }) ...
```

**Note that this not an ideal solution since it does not allow to control the size of the gap.**

### Specific Border Color for each category

The javascript version of the code for the chart can be used as follows:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: {
                    position: "bottom",
                    text: "Chart Title",
                },
                ...
                seriesDefaults: {
                    margin: 0,
                    type: "donut",
                    border: {
                        width: 1,
                        color: function (point) {
                            //Example
                            var color_data = {"cat1" : "blue", "cat2": "red"};
                            return color_data[point.category];
                        }
                    }
                }
                ...
```

The `seriesDefault.border.color` property can be set with a function that takes the relevant category object as an argument, it is possible then to implement logic that returns the appropriate color for each category.